# Is peak usage of 100% in "PS Old Gen" symptomatic of excessive garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am investigating loss of throughput problem in a web application running on Java 8 (1.8.0_45) and Tomcat 8 (8.0.26).

I have this information available about PS Old Gen memory usage:

```
"PS Old Gen" (Heap memory)
--------------------------
Current usage 535451120/716177408 (74.77%, 180726288 free)
  Max possible 716177408   
Peak usage 716170120/716177408 (100.00%, 7288 free)
  Max possible 716177408   
Usage after last GC 351438392/716177408 (49.07%, 364739016 free)
  Max possible 716177408
```

We are using these settings (amongst others that I believe are irrelevant):

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
```

Is it normal that PS Old Gen would completely fill?  Is a collection of this space only triggered when it becomes full, or would it typically occur sooner?

I do not believe there is a long-running memory leak as usage after last GC shows only 49% usage.  The application also generally has good uptime without showing increase in overall heap usage (as monitored through JMX).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that it recovered 51% is promising, but the real question is how often Full GC  is running.  You can turn on GC logging to surmise more information as to how often you are having GC run, how long it is blocking, and the type of GC being run.  This is turned on via -Xloggc:*path*, there are additional details that can be turned on as well such as -XX:PrintGCDetails and -XX:PrintGCTimeStamps

Comment: Thankyou, we will put out a version with GC logging enabled and see if it happens again.  We also re-enabled `UseGCOverheadLimit` as that may have been masking the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable GC logging to a file as @Michael suggested. And yes since the full GC is "stop the world" action as far as application threads are concerned, its frequency would be real cause of concern. A very helpful tool in visualizing and having a summary of GC is [GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer) which can help you lot in visualizing what's going on in the JVM for the time period of GC statistics collection. I would suggest to collect the GC information of your app server for considerable time during which you think the throughput is suffering and then use GCViewer. It has helped us lot in such analysis.